# Correct use of BeginReceive / EndReceive?

Tags: c#, sockets

To asynchronously receive data from a socket .Net supports symmetrical BeginReceive/EndReceive calls.  Basically you call `BeginReceive()` to start listening and to identify a callback which should be called when the data arrives.    Inside the callback you call `EndReceive()` to extract the data and end the asynchronous read operation.

I'm writing C#/.Net software to control some industrial equipment.   A control panel allows users to set up and initialize the equipment and once it's initialized `BeginReceive()` is called start listening for data.    In the callback `EndReceive()` is used to extract the data, but I want to resume listening right away so I think I should call `BeginReceive()` again right after doing the `EndReceive()`.   Is this correct?

If so, is there a check or test I can use elsewhere in the code to know whether `BeginReceive()` has already been called so I don't try to call `BeginReceive()` twice in a row on the same socket, before `EndReceive()` has been called?

Comment: That is correct. I don't know if you can check if its already been called though (apart from your own custom flag). Its quite possible that two calls to `BeginRecieve` wouldn't do anything anyways; check the documentation.

Comment: `Socket`, or rather the OS, checks for this itself. If you attempt to call `BeginReceive` while another receive is already in progress, it will throw an exception representing the socket error WSAEALREADY (I think). After all, there isn't much sense in trying to receive into two buffers from the same socket simultaneously!

But if you ask whether there is a property on `Socket` that tells you whether an operation is in progress, the answer is no (it'd be useless anyway because of the inescapable race condition). You can implement your own locking if you need to.

Comment: You should not call begin receive in a way that would cause a reentrancy.. that's for sure. if you encounter a situation where you need a flag to know if you called it or not - it probably means your architecture is incorrect.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy: "If you attempt to call BeginReceive while another receive is already in progress, it will throw an exception"  This is not correct. In fact, issuing multiple receive operation (i.e. calling `BeginReceive()` multiple times) is a strategy commonly used when dealing with IOCP-based I/O (as the Socket class is). The trick is, while the buffers will be filled in the order in which they were submitted via the receive operations, the completion events may occur out of order. So the caller does need to keep track of their buffer order and ensure they are processed correctly.

Comment: Feel free to have a look at my [.NET Sockets](https://github.com/perrybutler/dotnetsockets) repo on Github which uses BeingReceive/EndReceive patterns. And [here](https://github.com/perrybutler/csharpsockets) is the C# version.

Comment: @Peter Ah, that must be why MSDN on WSAEALREADY only mentions `connect` and not `send`/`recv`! Thanks, glad to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you avoid calling `BeginReceive()` again before you've called `EndReceive()` is to put the call to `BeginReceive()` into the completion callback where you call `EndReceive()`. The only call to `BeginReceive()` that should not be executed there is, of course, the one you make immediately after the `Socket` has connected.

EDIT:

To be clear: it is permitted to call `BeginReceive()` any number of times before any receive completion happens. But when you do that, you need to make sure you do the necessary housekeeping to ensure you process the data in the right order (i.e. you process the buffers in the same order in which you submitted them via `BeginReceive()`).

So the above answer is about not having to do all that housekeeping and thus keeping the code simpler.

If you only ever make your subsequent calls to `BeginReceive()` in the same place where you are calling `EndReceive()`, it's trivial to keep things in order. Note though that you still need to do that right: the simplest way to ensure you are always receiving the buffers in the right order is to simply not call `BeginReceive()` again until *after* you've called `EndReceive()` (but still in the same method).

Comment: Just to be sure I understand your answer:  I think you're saying there should be exactly TWO calls to BeginReceive() - one where the socket is first connected and one in the callback/handler.  The first BeginReceive() is only called once, all subsequent calls to BeginReceive are from the handler, right after EndReceive().   Is this correct?

Comment: For simplest implementation, yes. As I mentioned in the comments to the question, you _can_ call `BeginReceive()` multiple times, but then you have to do housekeeping to make sure you process the received data in the right order. I'll add some clarification to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to call `BeginReceive` after you are done receiving the data in order to get more down the road when data becomes available.

It's up to you to handle the state of the `Socket` where you do not call `BeginReceive` twice. There are properties available to let you know whether data is available, but nothing that tells you whether you are already waiting to receive data.

Most implementations of `Socket` end up being another wrapper class that has this logic in place so that `BeginReceive` is ignored if called a 2nd time. The `Socket` class is kind of a pain at times since you cannot cancel a `BeginReceive` without closing.