# How do I correctly read and write with a Socket/NetworkStream using C# async/await in a single thread?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, async-await, networkstream

I'm attempting to write a client in C# for a proprietary TCP protocol connection (that sends/receives key+value pair messages). I'm wanting to use the `async`/`await` features of `NetworkStream` so my program can read and write to the socket with a single thread (*a la* JavaScript) however I'm having problems with the way `NetworkStream.ReadAsync` works.

Here's my program in outline:

```
public static async Task Main(String[] args)
{
    using( TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient() )
    {
        await tcp.ConnectAsync( ... );
        using( NetworkStream ns = tcp.GetStream() )
        {
            while( true )
            {
                await RunInnerAsync( ns );
            }
        }
    }
}

private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<NameValueCollection> pendingMessagesToSend = new ConcurrentQueue<NameValueCollection>();

private static async Task RunInnerAsync( NetworkStream ns )
{
    // 1. Send any pending messages.
    // 2. Read any newly received messages.

    // 1:
    while( !pendingMessagesToSend.IsEmpty )
    {
        // ( foreach Message, send down the NetworkStream here )
    }

    // 2:
    Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
    while( ns.DataAvailable )
    {
        Int32 bytesRead = await ns.ReadAsync( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
        if( bytesRead == 0 ) break;
        // ( process contents of `buffer` here )
    } 
}
```

There's a problem here: if there is no data in the `NetworkStream ns` to be read (`DataAvailable == false`) then the `while( true )` loop in `Main` constantly runs and the CPU never idles - this is bad.

So if I change the code to remove the `DataAvailable` check and simply always call `ReadAsync` then the call effectively "blocks" until data is available - so if no data arrives then this client will never send any messages to the remote host. So I thought about adding a timeout of 500ms or so:

```
// 2:
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
while( ns.DataAvailable )
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource( 500 );
    Task<Int32> readTask = ns.ReadAsync( buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cts.Token );
    await readTask;
    if( readTask.IsCancelled ) break;
    // ( process contents of `buffer` here )
}
```

[However, this does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421989/networkstream-readasync-with-a-cancellation-token-never-cancels)! Apparently the `NetworkStream.ReadAsync` overload that accepts a `CancellationToken` does not abort or stop when a cancellation is actually requested, it always ignores it (how is this not a bug?).

The QA I linked to suggests a workaround of simply closing the `Socket`/`NetworkStream` - which is inappropriate for me because I need to keep the connection alive, but only *take a break* from waiting for data to arrive and send some data instead.

[One of the other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20910003/159145) suggests co-awaiting a `Task.Delay`, like so:

```
// 2:
Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];
while( ns.DataAvailable )
{
    Task maxReadTime = Task.Delay( 500 );
    Task readTask = ns.ReadAsync( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
    await Task.WhenAny( maxReadTime, readTask );
    if( maxReadTime.IsCompleted )
    {
        // what do I do here to cancel the still-pending ReadAsync operation?
    }
}
```

...however while this does stop the program from waiting for an indefinite network read operation, *it doesn't stop the read operation itself* - so when my program finishes sending any pending messages it will call into `ReadAsync` a second time while it's still waiting for data to arrive - and that means dealing with overlapped-IO and is not what I want at all.

[I know when working with `Socket` directly and its `BeginReceive` / `EndReceive` methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26807016/159145) you simply only ever call `BeginReceive` from within `EndReceive` - but how does one safely call `BeginReceive` for the first time, especially in a loop - and how should those calls be modified when using the `async/await` API instead?

Comment: Maybe you cah add `SpinWait` struct instead of `while (true)`, so eventually the main thread will yield the execution?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by getting the `Task` from `NetworkStream.ReadAsync` and storing it in a mutable local variable that is set to `null` if there is no pending `ReadAsync` operation, otherwise it's an valid `Task` instance.

Unfortunately as `async` methods cannot have `ref` parameters I needed to move my  logic into `Main` from `RunInnerAsync`.

Here's my solution:

```
private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<NameValueCollection> pendingMessagesToSend = new ConcurrentQueue<NameValueCollection>();
private static TaskCompletionSource<Object> queueTcs;

public static async Task Main(String[] args)
{
    using( TcpClient tcp = new TcpClient() )
    {
        await tcp.ConnectAsync( ... );
        using( NetworkStream ns = tcp.GetStream() )
        {
            Task<Int32> nsReadTask = null; // <-- this!
            Byte[] buffer = new Byte[1024];

            while( true )
            {
                if( nsReadTask == null )
                {
                    nsReadTask = ns.ReadAsync( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
                }

                if( queueTcs == null ) queueTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Object>();

                Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny( nsReadTask, queueTcs.Task );
                if( completedTask == nsReadTask )
                {
                    while( ns.DataAvailable )
                    {
                        Int32 bytesRead = await ns.ReadAsync( buffer, 0, buffer.Length );
                        if( bytesRead == 0 ) break;
                        // ( process contents of `buffer` here )
                    } 
                }
                else if( completedTask == queueTcs )
                {
                    while( !pendingMessagesToSend.IsEmpty )
                    {
                        // ( foreach Message, send down the NetworkStream here )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever `pendingMessagesToSend` is modified, the `queueTcs` is instantiated if null and has `SetResult(null)` called to un-await the `Task completedTask = await Task.WhenAny( nsReadTask, queueTcs.Task );` line.

Since building this solution I don't feel as though I'm using `TaskCompletionSource` appropriately, see this QA: [Is it acceptable to use TaskCompletionSource as a WaitHandle substitute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49727015/is-it-acceptable-to-use-taskcompletionsource-as-a-waithandle-substitute)